# Get resources from a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, zip

i want my jar file to access some files from itself. I know how to do this for `BufferedImage` but this doesn't work for other files. All i want is to extract some zips from my jar. i made a class folder in eclipse, put the zips inside and used

```
    public File getResFile(String name){

    return new File(getClass().getResource(name).getFile());


}
```

to get the `File` instance and extract it. it works fine in eclipse, but as soon as i export it to a jar it says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\DeLL\Desktop\BoxcraftClient\ClientInstaller.jar!\client.bxc (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
    at Launcher.install(Launcher.java:43)
    at Launcher.main(Launcher.java:33)
```

Im working to fix this already something like 6 hours and can't find a solution. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a reason why `getResource()` returns a `URL`, and not a `File`, because the resource may not *be* a file, and since your code is packaged in the Jar file, it's not a file but a zip entry.

The only safe way to read the content of the resource, is as an `InputStream`, either by calling `getResourceAsStream()` or by calling `openStream()` on the returned `URL`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

first check your class path using java `System.out.println("classpath is: " + System.getProperty("java.class.path"));` to see if the classpath has your jar file.

And then use the getclass().classloader.getResourceAsStream(name). See if the returned URL is correct. Call the method isFile() on the URL to check if the URL is actually a file. And then call the getFile() method.

Comment: Well, this would have fixed it, but i read the top one first, so i accepted that one as the correct one. Sorry and thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these methods, from the class [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)
- [getResource(java.lang.String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String))
- [getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))

```
    this.getClass().getResource(name);
    this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(name);
```

**Warning:** By default it loads the file from the location, where the `this.class`, is found in the package. So if using it from a class `org.organisation.project.App`, then the file need to be inside the jar in the directory `org/organisation/project`. In case the file is located in the root, or some other directory, inside the jar, use the `/`, in from of the file name. Like `/data/names.json`.

Comment: Well, this would have fixed it, but i read the top one first, so i accepted that one as the correct one. Sorry and thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

Use Spring's **PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver**;

It will do the trick for both launching the package from an IDE or from the file system:

```
public List<String> getAllClassesInRunningJar() throws Exception {
    try {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Get all the classes inside the package com.my.package:
        // This will do the work for both launching the package from an IDE or from the file system:  
        String scannedPackage = "com.my.package.*";

        // This is spring - org.springframework.core; use these imports:
        //  import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
        //  import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver scanner = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        Resource[] resources = scanner.getResources(scannedPackage.replace(".", "/"));

        for (Resource resource : resources)
            list.add(resource.getURI().toString());
        return list ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to get the classes: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```